# IntelliJ IDEA with SBT: ANDROID_HOME not found

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to run a Android project on IntellyJ IDEA with SBT. However it fails with `"[error] set ANDROID_HOME ..."`. Of cause I have setup ANDROID_HOME and I'm able to build and run the project from command line with sbt. Why does IntellyJ IDEA can't find it?

Answer (score 1):

You should run run IDEA from the same terminal window in which you've set ANDROID_HOME environment vaiable. For example in Linux/Mac terminal:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android-sdk
cd /path/to/intelijIdea/bin
./idea.sh
```

If you want to set `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable system-wide, and not repeat this process each time you run IDEA, in Linux you should add

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android-sdk
```

to end of `~/.bashrc` file. You can do this from terminal:

```
printf "\nexport ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android-sdk" >> ~/.bashrc
```

$ANDROID_HOME will be available after log out and back in, or run `source ~/.bashrc` to make it available **in current shell** immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can set "Project SDK" to some Android SDK not normal JDK, and the plugins can use correct ANDROID_HOME.